# Shorter way of inserting form data into database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that returns all of the below data

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$env1 = $_POST['environment[com1]'];
$env2 = $_POST['environment[com2]'];
$env3 = $_POST['environment[com3]'];
$hltCode = $_POST['hlType[code]'];
$hltDB = $_POST['hlType[db]'];
$hltWCF = $_POST['hlType[wcf]'];
$tfsID = $_POST['tfsID'];
$release = $_POST['release'];
$createdBy = 'mhopkins';
$updatedBy = 'mhopkins';
```

This of course leads to a VERY long query like the following

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO patches (name, description, type, com1, com2, bofa, code, db, wcf, tfsID, release, createdBy, updatedBy) VALUES ('".$name."','".$description."''".$type."','".$envCom1."','".$envCom2."','".$envBofA."','".$hltCode."','".$hltDB."','".$hltWCF."','".$tfsID."','".$release."','".$createdBy."','".$updatedBy."'")
$insertResult = $link->query($insertQuery);
```

The values section has a LOT of punctuation and many possibilities for typos. If I have my variable names be the same as the field columns, is there an easier/shorter way to do this?

Comment: Prepared statements and :named parameters.

Comment: If by "easier" you mean "avoiding the need to investigate how an intruder got in after you've been hacked", then yes: sanitize your inputs/parameterize your queries to protect against SQL injection. ;-) (Humor intended, not snark. In all seriousness, do be careful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has sql injection vulnerabilities, I wouldn't run that code even from a trusted source.

You can try using an ORM like Idiorm, it will manage the column names and escape variables for you https://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html?highlight=insert https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/

```
require_once 'idiorm.php';

ORM::configure(array(
    'connection_string' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database',
    'username' => 'database_user',
    'password' => 'top_secret'
));

$patch = ORM::for_table('patches')->create($_POST);
$patch->createdBy = 'mhopkins';
$patch->updatedBy = 'mhopkins';
$patch->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use variables to get the data out of $_POST and reuse them in the SQL string.

Like:

```
<?php 
$descriptionFieldName = "description";
$description = $_POST[$descriptionFieldName];
$sql = "INSERT INTO patches ($descriptionFieldName) VALUES ($description);
?>
```

Not much shorter, well, even longer. Though this way you are only typing the form input name and the SQL column name once.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try mapping an array to do the job for you, something like:

```
$dbColumnsToValues = array(
    'column_1' => $_POST['column1'],
    'column_2' => $_POST['column2'],
);
$columns = "'" . implode("',", array_keys($dbColumnsToValues)) . "'";
$values  = "'" . implode("',", array_map(array($link, 'escape'), array_values($dbColumnsToValues))) . "'";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `some_table` (".$columns.") VALUES(".$values.")";
```

Not tested though, but you should get the point.
Also, assuming your `$link` object has an `escape` method that will make sure your input won't trigger an sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you have a table consisting of 3 columns: `col0`, `col1`, `col2`. 
If you are inserting all the fields that are present in the table and in the same order, you can omit listing the column names in the query. Like instead of

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col0`, `col1`, `col2`) VALUES ("{$val0}", "{$val1}", "{$val2}",);
```

try

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ("{$val0}", "{$val1}", "{$val2}");
```

PS: PLease sanitize the variable values before using them in the query.